# tensorflow function that projects max value to 1 and others -1 without using zeros

Tags: tensorflow

How can I make `x` from `y` where

```
x = tf.constant([[1,5,3], [100,20,3]])
y = ([[-1,1,-1], [1,-1,-1]])
```

So it basically projects the max value to 1 and makes other elements to -1. One important constraint is we should not use zero. (Because if I use zero, the gradient does not flow on that node.) Using `tf.argmax` we can get the max indices but don't really know how to make `y` from it.

Could you please help?

**For pedagogical purpose I set `x` as constant, but in the actual problem I'am solving, `x` is actually a placeholder that gets inputs of a network.**

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tf.reduce_max` to calculate the `max` per row, compare with original tensor, and use `tf.where` to set values conditionally:

```
x = tf.constant([[1,5,3], [100,20,3]])

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(
    tf.where(
        tf.equal(tf.reduce_max(x, axis=1, keep_dims=True), x), 
        tf.constant(1, shape=x.shape), 
        tf.constant(-1, shape=x.shape)
    )
)

array([[-1,  1, -1],
       [ 1, -1, -1]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. It is my mistake that I didn't mention the differentiability of the operation. If I simply replace in this way, it's not really differentiable and that's a problem for me. Can we do that we only change 0 to -1, multiply 1/|x_i| with x_i where x_i is the max value, and multiply -1/|x_j| with other x_j's? Using tf.where is it possible?

Comment: So max should be `1`, other values (!=0) should be `x/max` and `0` should be `-1`?

Comment: No. The result should be the same (I mean the output). Other values (!=0) should be -1 as well.  But we make it by dividing it by the negative absolute value of it.

Comment: Though I am not sure how it affects the differentiability but maybe `-tf.div(x, tf.abs(x))` to replace `tf.constant(-1,...)`. If you need to set up `0` specifically, then you might need to chain another `tf.where(tf.equal(x, 0), ...)`

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try!

Answer (score 0):

Following is much cleaner solution that works for me:

```
y = tf.one_hot(tf.argmax(x, axis=1), x.shape[1], on_value=1, off_value=-1)
```

Basically, tf.argmax gives you the index of the max value along the dimension 1 and the one_hot method creates the desired tesnor.